# GIT PUSH ERROR failed to push some refs

Tags: git

Me quedo guardado el directorio de mis imagenes de un repo en las descargas, descargue un archivo ahi y luego me olvide, quise commitear unos cambios y se intento subir ese archivo que es mas largo de 120 mb lo cual da error en git, el problema es el siguiente: borre el archivo descargado y quise commitear de nuevo pero se ve que el commit queda remoto y no puedo commitear nada ya que intento y me dice que el archivo es mas grande blabla dejo lo que me dice git

> git push Enumerating objects: 26, done. Counting objects: 100%
> (26/26), done. Delta compression using up to 4 threads Compressing
> objects: 100% (20/20), done. Writing objects: 100% (20/20), 97.40 MiB
> | 6.08 MiB/s, done. Total 20 (delta 14), reused 0 (delta 0),
> pack-reused 0 remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (14/14), completed with 6
> local objects. remote: error: Trace:
> e28b461f1242d7e8ee198824536fc0e72f24848f2fde199eaacb86e78e69ad24
> remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information. remote:
> error: File src/assets/img/eclipse-inst-jre-win64.exe is 120.36 MB;
> this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB remote: error:
> GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File
> Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com. To
> https://github.com/manuacostaok/FrontEnd-YoProgramo  ! [remote
> rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined) error: failed
> to push some refs to
> 'https://github.com/manuacostaok/FrontEnd-YoProgramo'

Comment: Por curiosidad, ¿Has leído el contenido del primer enlace que el error te dice? Te lleva aquí: https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/about-large-files-on-github#removing-files-from-a-repositorys-history y tiene código de comandos para utilizar. Es probable que la solución se encuentre en dichos pasos. Saludos.

Comment: Use los comandos y me dice 
fatal: pathspec 'eclipse-inst-jre-win64.exe' did not match any files
tambien puse la ruta donde esta el archivo y nada, me dice lo mismo.

Comment: intenta esto: `git rm src/assets/img/eclipse-inst-jre-win64.exe` ¿qué te sale?

Comment: Si quieres borrar un commit remoto, aquí hay información: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3293531/13419694

Comment: si hago lo que me decis fredyx me sale esto:
fatal: pathspec 'src/assets/img/eclipse-inst-jre-win64.exe' did not match any files

Comment: recien hice git reset --hard y despues git push --force y me salio:
 HEAD is now at e783481 act src

despues del push me volvio a salir como que intenta commitear el archivo grande y me vuelve a decir lo mismo

Answer (score 0):

PUDE SOLUCIONAR HACIENDO LO SIGUIENTE :

```
git reset HEAD^ --hard
```

ESTO VUELVE AL ULTIMO COMMIT

y a continuación forzando los cambios al repositorio remoto de origen con:

```
git push origin -f
```

CON ESTO PUSHEO EL COMMIT DE NUEVO Y ME TIRO ERROR DE NUEVO,
VOLVI A HACER EL PRIMER CODIGO Y LUEGO
git push
me dio error porq estaba desincronizado el repo
le di a
git pull
y luego ya estaba todo ok

MUCHAS GRACIAS A TODOS LO QUE ME AYUDARON

Comment: https://www.campusmvp.es/recursos/post/como-eliminar-el-ultimo-commit-de-git-en-el-repositorio-de-origen-p-ej-github.aspx 

este link me fue de ayuda!